# Host.json with only local settings

Tags: azure, azure-functions, localhost

I'm working on a Azure Function project and for integration with FrontEnd purposes, I need to add a route prefix on the endpoints that is served by the application.

Right now, I'm adding the following code to my host.json.

```
{
 "extensions": {
    "http": { "routePrefix": "template" }
}
```

But this happens to break my application when I upload to my cloud.

Is there any way to have a add this code only locally or have a host.json configuration that just work locally?

Answer (score 0):

We have created a .Net function app with Http trigger using visual studio code 2019. we have added the below route prefix to the `host.json` of the Http Trigger function & tested in local environment which is working fine.

Here is our `host.json` file & we haven't done  any changes to the default function.Cs file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "extensions": { "http": { "routePrefix": "template" } }
  }
}
```

Here is the reference output from when we ran the function visual studio code :

[image]

Since we don't found any issues in our local environment we have pushed same code to a function app running in azure with .net as a runtime .
Post deploying code to function app we have tested the function by invoking the function url from PowerShell & it is succeeded.

Here is the reference output screen shot:

[image]

Here is the reference blog about [creation of routing in Azure function app](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/routing-in-azure-function/)